# Pandas get day value from date string column in python

Tags: python, string, date, pandas, dataframe

Reading the Dataset:

```
visits=   pd.read_csv('tracker.csv', low_memory=False, parse_dates=     
['Date_Time'])
df= pd.DataFrame(visits)
```

This is how data looks:

```
print(df.head(n=1))
Date_Time       IPAddress  Visitors      OS        Browser  \
0 2016-10-18 12:57:45  104.236.233.18      1001  Mac OS  Google Chrome   
Browser_Version Location                     Referrer     PageID  
0    39.0.2171.95      NaN  http://www.puneetmathur.in/  index.php
```

Problem is with Date_Time column:

```
import datetime
df['new_date'] = [d.date() for d in df['Date_Time']]
df['new_time'] = [d.time() for d in df['Date_Time']]
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['new_date']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['new_date']).month
```

Purpose is to get for month = 12 all the Days from 1 to 30 or 31 or 28 depending on the month.

Converting to String below and split values to access the DAY value after split:

```
strdt=str(df.new_date)
df['new_date']=df['new_date'].astype(str)
df['new_date']=df.new_date.apply(str)
type(df.new_date)
df['new_day']=df.new_date.str.split('-')
```

The Pandas Dataframe has more than 1000 rows so that is not the problem:

```
print(df.new_day)
print(df.new_day)
0       [2016, 10, 18]
1       [2016, 10, 18]
2       [2016, 10, 18]
3       [2016, 10, 18]
4       [2016, 10, 18]
5       [2016, 10, 18]
6       [2016, 10, 19]
7       [2016, 10, 19]
8       [2016, 10, 19]
9       [2016, 10, 19]
10      [2016, 10, 19]
11      [2016, 10, 19]
12      [2016, 10, 19]
13      [2016, 10, 19]
14      [2016, 10, 19]
15      [2016, 10, 19]
16      [2016, 10, 19]
17      [2016, 10, 19]
18      [2016, 10, 20]
19      [2016, 10, 20]
20      [2016, 10, 20]
```

I want to access the third value after the 2nd comma two digit number
    print(df['new_day'][6][2])
    19

So far so good..

I now filter Date with Month first and then try to access the value after 2nd comma the 2 digit value with following code:

```
value_list = [12]
vdf= pd.DataFrame(df[df.month.isin(value_list)])
print(vdf[:][:].head(n=1))
print(vdf[:][:].head(n=1))
Date_Time     IPAddress  Visitors          OS       Browser  \
2836 2016-12-11 01:25:25  66.102.8.217      3955  Search Bot  Apple Safari   
Browser_Version                Location                     Referrer  \
2836               9  Florida, United States  http://www.puneetmathur.in/   

PageID    new_date  new_time  year  month         new_day  
2836  index.php  2016-12-11  01:25:25  2016     12  [2016, 12, 11]
```

When I try to access the 2nd value it gives the strange output:

```
vdf['new_day'][:][:2].str.split('-')
Out[250]: Series([], Name: new_day, dtype: object)
```

The below also does not work to give me all the values in the 3rd column of new_day after the 2nd comma.
Please tell me how can I access the DAY value in the 3rd column of new_day

```
vdf.iloc[:,:]
```

Comment: this is too long!  Basic advice here:  just store one column as a pandas datetime.  Access values with dt accessors (See docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor  )With pandas it is generally a bad idea to store lists in columns.  If you have a single column with a list of length 3, you'll find it much better to instead store it as 3 separate columns with a single value in each column (or even better here, just store as a single column of dtype datetime then use dt accessors)

Comment: Not sure why you're passing `parse_dates` in `read_csv` and then you reverse all the good work by trying to cast back to string. Basically once you've done the parsing you can access the datetime attributes using `.dt` so day would be `df['Date_Time'].dt.day`, month `...dt.month` and year likewise. If you want just the date then you can also do `dt.date` but this gives you a `datetime.date` object which is less useful but more useful than a string

Comment: Hey @EdChum your suggestion df['Date_Time'].dt.day works wonderfully further the below ones work as well:   df['Date_Time'].dt.day
df['Date_Time'].dt.month
df['Date_Time'].dt.year
df['Date_Time'].dt.date
df['Date_Time'].dt.time
df['Date_Time'].dt.hour
df['Date_Time'].dt.minute
df['Date_Time'].dt.second                                                                                                        Thanks once again EdChum I accept this as the answer

Comment: Any idea @EdChum on how to select Month==12 the following code gives error:                                                                                                                           df['Date_Time'].dt.month=='12'                                                                                     TypeError: invalid type comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I face the same problem solved with the following code:

```
df['Date_Time'].dt.day
```

Try it should work for you.
The wonderful part is you have already taken care of conversion to datetime even as you import. 
Now you just need to access the day with dt.day that is all.

Comment: Thanks Hillary much appreciated This does work for me now.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very confusing, but I think you want to filter by month == 12.

If you want to do something with every month for example count or get unique values, you can use groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u'''Date_Time,IPAddress,Visitors,OS,Browser
2016-10-18 12:57:45,104.236.233.1,1001,Mac OS1,Google Chrome
2016-10-17 12:57:45,104.236.233.2,1002,Mac OS2,Google Chrome
2016-11-16 12:57:45,104.236.233.3,1003,Mac OS3,Google Chrome
2016-11-15 12:57:45,104.236.233.3,1004,Mac OS4,Google Chrome
2016-12-16 12:57:45,104.236.233.5,1005,Mac OS5,Google Chrome
2016-12-15 12:57:45,104.236.233.6,1006,Mac OS6,Google Chrome
'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['Date_Time'])

# Filter month equal 12
df[df['Date_Time'].dt.month == 12]

            #~ Date_Time      IPAddress  Visitors       OS        Browser
#~ 4 2016-12-16 12:57:45  104.236.233.5      1005  Mac OS5  Google Chrome
#~ 5 2016-12-15 12:57:45  104.236.233.6      1006  Mac OS6  Google Chrome

# Groupby month
gb = df.groupby(df['Date_Time'].dt.month)

# Count by month
gb.count()

 #~ Date_Time  IPAddress  Visitors  OS  Browser
#~ Date_Time                                             
#~ 10                 2          2         2   2        2
#~ 11                 2          2         2   2        2
#~ 12                 2          2         2   2        2


# Unique ip by month
gb.IPAddress.unique()

#~ Date_Time
#~ 10    [104.236.233.1, 104.236.233.2]
#~ 11                   [104.236.233.3]
#~ 12    [104.236.233.5, 104.236.233.6]
#~ Name: IPAddress, dtype: object
```

Comment: The question did not want to groupby() That I have already done I want to access df['Date_Time'].dt.day to access the day inside the date time which is the excellent solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date_Time'].dt.day
```

I accept this answer from The @edchums who took out the pains to run the query and explain how day and other such items can be extracted from the simple date time column in python.

A great answer deserves a standing ovation!